# How do I output my AWS Lambda function to a list?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Currently I am attempting to output an AWS Bucket's key's(files) to a list, so that I can compare that to another list I assigned before the handler. However, after I append the key to a list, the list comes back blank when I call it later.

My code example:

```
#my imports
import boto3

#my assigned values
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
1stList = ['1','2','3','4']
appendList = []
myBucket = s3.Bucket('bucketName')

#my function handler
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for obj in my_bucket.objects.all():
            key = obj.key 
            appendList.append(key)

print(appendList)
```

The output of the print statement is then just: []

Then if I attempt to call this list later, it shows as blank.

Comment: What do you mean by later? Show the code that's failing.

Answer (score 3):

An AWS Lambda is mostly stateless and definitely distributed.  What that means is that when you call your code a second (or more) time you may or may not get the same execution environment again.  So, while you modified the `appendList` it's very possible that the next time your Lambda is called you are getting a brand new "run" of your Lambda and the array is empty.  This is especially true if several minutes have passed since the last call.  *Sometimes* if you call the Lambda twice in about 5 minutes you'll get the same environment.  But there is zero guarantee for that.

If you need to save the keys coming in from the S3 event you'll need to use some sort of persistent store like a DynamoDB, RDS, or even a file on an EFS volume.